# .htaccess how to load rewrited page instead redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a pure HTML/CSS/PHP blog. Structure is simple.
Main page is domain.com/blog (latest posts) and domain.com/blog?page=2 (for posts in page 2 etc).
That page is controlled by blog.php file. If user want to read post for example "How-to-learn-polish" he goes to domain.com/blog_post?name=How-to-learn-polish and this is also work.

My problem is, how to write rule in htaccess to load content of page 
`domain.com/blog_post?name=How-to-learn-polish`
in url
`domain.com/blog/How-to-learn-polish`

I searched on internet solution for my problem and i create that rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ blog_post.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
```

This rule works ok in 80% because it redirect from
`domain.com/blog/How-to-learn-polish`
to
`domain.com/blog_post?name=How-to-learn-polish`

I don't want to redirect but load post in this URL `domain.com/blog/How-to-learn-polish`

What i should to change in my htaccess to do that? Full of my htaccess look like this

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ blog_post.php?name=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rules need reordering:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ blog_post.php?name=$1 [END,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Make sure to use a different browser or remove cache data from your browser to test this rule to avoid old cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I tested Your solution and that is fully working. All i need to do i fix urls to CSS and <img src> to absolute not relative but You fully help with my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: To fix css/js issue, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.